# Can I ask previous job interview: What was wrong?

Tags: interviewing

I had an interview not long ago (3 months) at a big international company. There were 170 applicants and at the end it stood between me and another guy. The other guy got it. The manager said it was because the other guy had a more suitable background. But me and that manager found a really good and friendly tone.

I now have a new interview at a completly different company, could I send an email to the first company manager and say something like this:

> Hi Eric. Hope all is well? I just wanted to ask you a quick question.
>   Im having a new interview next week at "Levi´s" and Im wondering if
>   you have any good pointers for me from our last interview? Maybe there
>   was something you reacted on or just general pointers that Ive could
>   have done differently?

Answer (score 14):

You were number 2 out of 170. You didn't do anything wrong. Your feeling that you had a good rapport with the interviewer was probably accurate. Don't go fishing for "What did I do wrong?" Instead ask, "What could I have emphasized better?"

That being said, yes I think it's not unreasonable to ask a small kindly bit of feedback from someone you got along with. Just keep it short and professional and respect any answer you might get, including none at all.

Comment: I can't agree, if someone emailed me in this vein, they would literally seem like a high-schooler or (maybe) a college student.

Comment: @Fattie You aren't *entirely* wrong. Writing this email without sounding needy and whiny will be exceedingly difficult but I still think doable.

Answer (score 1):

The company already answered with what is all they're going to say:

> [...] the other guy had a more suitable background.[...]

Move on and good luck hunting.

Answer (score -1):

I have to say "No".

If you think about it, three facts are

1. You will learn absolutely nothing from this. Even if the person thinks about it and meaningfully responds, what can he say?  Only platitudes and generalities.
2. In job-hunting, you want to ***only ever appear strong, never weak for any reason***.  It is miserable and childish to say, Dear Sir what can I do better. At that manager and company you'll be "marked" as a bit of a pansy-ass, you know?
3. The overwhelming reality is the person simply won't have time to respond to such a request from someone he happened to interview once. Likely it will just be annoying.

I can see no upside at all, and many downsides in this.

Comment: 1 and 3 are certainly valid points. 2 is less so. First they already didn't get the job and will likely never see that manager again even if they apply at that company again. But even if they did they already exposed their weakness. That's why they didn't get the job. Lastly, and not everyone sees this the same as me, but I perceive attempting to identify and overcome ones weaknesses as a strength. Have an upcoming nonetheless.

Comment: @bruglesco - right; but on the moderate chance they ever have to do business again with that boss, point 2 surely applies.

Comment: Hah that was supposed to say upvotes. Stupid autocorrect

Comment: LOL good one.  we need more wine.

Comment: Yes, I´ve thought about it and decided not to mention it. But thank you both for your input. Much obliged